# how do i read logserver file fully?

Tags: c#

i use that code to read lines like this from txt file

```
2017-07-01 22:12:59 0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   Mads    Sarag           hello iam Sarag
2017-07-01 22:13:05 0   0   3   2   4   0   0   0   0   Mads    Sarag           hello iam Sarag
```

but last column display one string in data gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1azj.png)

code

```
 class ReadPublicChat
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk1 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk2 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk3 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk4 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk5 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk6 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk7 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk8 { get; set; }
    public Int64 unk9 { get; set; }
    public string AccName { get; set; }
    public string CharName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public static List<ReadPublicChat> LoadPublicChat(string path)
    {
        var PublicChat = new List<ReadPublicChat>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            string[] Columns = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (line.Length > 0)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt64(Columns[9]) == 0)
                {
                    PublicChat.Add(new ReadPublicChat
                    {
                        date = Columns[0],
                        time = Columns[1],
                        unk1 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[2]),
                        unk2 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[3]),
                        unk3 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[4]),
                        unk4 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[5]),
                        unk5 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[6]),
                        unk6 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[7]),
                        unk7 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[8]),
                        unk8 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[9]),
                        unk9 = Convert.ToInt64(Columns[10]),
                        AccName = Columns[11],
                        CharName = Columns[12],
                        Message = Columns[13]

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        return PublicChat;
    }
}
```

i need someone edit this code to read file

please help to finish that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additional solution to *snixtho*'s answer is using [`ArraySegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) to slice `columns` array then join the items with `String.Join`, i.e.

```
Message = Columns.Length <= 13 ? "" : 
  String.Join(" ", new ArraySegment<string>(Columns, 13, Columns.Length - 13));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are splitting by space and tabs, the last "column" in the log line will also be split into multiple parts. So, `Columns[13]` will contain the first word, `Columns[14]` will contain the next word etc.

Just loop until the end of the Columns array from index 13, and join all parts with a space.

Example:

```
string message = "";
for (int i = 13; i < Columns.Length; i++) {
    message += Columns[i] + (i+1 == Columns.length ? "" : " ");
}
```

Ofcourse, this is assuming messages are never empty. If they can be empty, you should check that first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and help